# Importing CURL into block in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have a custom block that needs to request data from an external API. 
Examples refer to a construct like this:

```
class CustomerBalance extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
```

{

```
public function __construct(
  \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory $httpClientFactory
)
```

But that breaks the site and the page fails to load correctly without logging any errors.
I have the same problem trying to use GuzzleHttp when I import that.
I guess there is something I'm missing about Magento 2 importing...

Or is there another way to access the Magento curl object?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I was simply importing the wrong class. This works:

```
protected $_httpAdapter;

public function __construct(
  \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\Curl $httpAdapter
){
    $this->_httpAdapter = $httpAdapter;
  }
```

A more complete answer can be found here:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153993/magento-2-curl-send-header-with-response